# Feature Compare Tool giving ArcGIS Error 999999?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class, error-999999

I'm running the ArcGIS feature compare tool against 2 point feature class layers. I'm comparing 9.1 SDE layer against a 10.1 SDE layer.

In the feature compare tool one of the input options is 'continue comparison': I checked off the Continue_Compare option to run in order to check other properties after encountering the first mismatch. However, every time I check off this option, and run the tool is runs for >30 mins and I get Error 999999.

When I uncheck this option the tool runs smoothly and only takes <2 mins, without error.

Just wondering why there is a difference and an error occurs.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, could you please tell which version of ArcGIS you use? You've added the arcsde tag, are your features classes in an ArcSDE workspace?

Comment: Welcome to the site JennD.  999999 errors are difficult to troubleshoot as they are generic.  Any additional details you could provide would be helpful and will increase the chances of getting a useful answer.  For example, what type of fields are you comparing (e.g. text, float, etc)?  Are the datasets featureclasses in a FGDB (or PGDB) or shapefiles?

Comment: Is there a place to attach a file?, I could show you the information I was comparing. I'm basically comparing all field properties in the attribute table, spatial references, domains, extents, etc. Using the feature compare tool in Arc.

Comment: There is an an option in the tool called: continue_compare
which is Optional. It indicates whether to compare all properties after encountering the first mismatch - when checked or NO_CONTINUE_COMPARE —Stops after encountering the first mismatch. This is the default.
CONTINUE_COMPARE —Compares other properties after encountering the first mismatch.
Boolean

Comment: When I check the option off, the processing for comparison takes > 3om ins and then it encounters this 999999 error. Otherwise, if I uncheck and leave the default the process only takes < 3 mins and does not end in an error. 

I'm just wondering why there is this difference in the processing.

Comment: Seems like there's a problem with a feature that it encounters after some processing time. Run *Repair geometry* or *Check geometry* on your features to see if there's something wrong with it. Also, if you wish to add information to your question, use the Edit button right beneath it instead of comments.

Comment: Generally I would agree with you @Martin, however theoretically ArcSDE will not let you store an invalid geometry so Check/repair geometry should be redundant on SDE data as validation is done when the geometry is stored. It is possible that the problem arises from an underlying database extended transaction, perhaps exceeding a timeout or transaction limit. Extract both feature classes into fGDB or at least the 9.1 SDE data and try again, if it still fails look at your database logs for v10.1 SDE and see if there's an error there.

Comment: Did you try copying these ArcSDE feature classes out to a file geodatabase to do your feature comparison (and check/repair geometry, if needed) there?